# Reference or Ordinary C Type

Tags: c, gcc, macros

Here's a challenge question.  I would like to create a mask bitmap for an unknown variable type that might be an array.  For instance,

```
char ch;
int i;
int i_arr[2];

printf("The ordinary type for ch is %lu bytes.\n", sizeof(ORDINARY_TYPE(ch)));
printf("The ordinary type for i is %lu bytes.\n", sizeof(ORDINARY_TYPE(i)));
printf("The ordinary type for i_arr is %lu bytes.\n", sizeof(ORDINARY_TYPE(i_arr)));
```

The output should be:

```
The ordinary type for ch is 1 bytes.
The ordinary type for i is 4 bytes.
The ordinary type for i_arr is 4 bytes.
```

Sounds impossible?  It's not.  To give you a jump start I will provide my "solution" - be warned that it is very GCC specific although I wonder if the builtins could be rewritten to be more compiler agnostic.

```
#define IS_PTR(X) \
    __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(X), char*), \
        1, \
    __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(X), int8_t*), \
        1, \
    __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(X), uint8_t*), \
        1, \
        (((uintptr_t)((1 ? (X) : (uintmax_t)0)+1) - \
                (uintptr_t)(1 ? (X) : (uintmax_t)0)) != 1)? 1 : 0 \
    )))

#define ORDINARY_TYPE(X)    \
    typeof(* __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p( \
            typeof(*(IS_PTR(X)? (X) : (&(X)))), void), \
                ((X)), \
                (&(X)) \
    ))
```

Here I have taken advantage of the result from `IS_PTR(X)? (X) : (&(X))` returning `void *` if `X` is a pointer.  However, as a result, the GCC compiler gives the following warnings (depending on the type of `X`):

```
warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]
warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]
```

Can anyone do this without getting these warnings and make it 'friendlier'?

## Use

I am working on a general GPIO configuration library (lol).  I think that I have something fairly solid but obviously it will need more rigorous testing for other processors.  One of the 'golden nuggets' is configuring a GPIO pins' properties,

```
CPU_GPIO_CONFIG_PROP(gpio, pupd, 2);  // Pull up/down, Open Drain, or none
CPU_GPIO_CONFIG_PROP(gpio, af,   4);  // Alternative Functions
```

Where `CPU_GPIO_CONFIG_PROP` is defined like so,

```
extern struct cpu_gpio;
#define CPU_GPIO_CONFIG_PROP(_gpio, _prop, _size) ({ \
    struct cpu_gpio *bus = (_gpio)->bus_addr; \
    ORDINARY_TYPE( ((struct cpu_gpio *) 0)->_prop) prop_type; \
    const size_t prop_size = sizeof(prop_type); \
    const unsigned short pin = ((_size)*(_gpio)->pin) % (8*prop_size); \
    const typeof(prop_type) mask = ~(~((typeof(prop_type)) 0x0) << _size); \
    typeof(prop_type) *p = ((typeof(prop_type) *) &bus->_prop \
        + ((_size)*((_gpio)->pin)/(8*prop_size))); \
    *p = (*p & ~(mask << pin)) | (((typeof(prop_type)) gpio->_prop) << pin); \
})
```

PHEW!  Okay, someone is going to once again ask "Why?" (@nneonneo)... The simple answer ('cause this is getting too long) is that each GPIO property is generally `8*_size` < `sizeof(int)` (32 bit ARM processor).  Here `_size` is the number of bits that the property takes to describe it.  However, it is possible for a property to exceed this requirement and therefore take `8*_size` > `sizeof(int)`.  In this case, the property takes up `int[n]` space in memory and will require some additional math to figure out (as I have already done above).  In my example, `af` takes 4 bits to describe (5 possible alternative functions to select from).  For 16 pins this becomes 4*16 > 32 and therefore takes `int[2]` to describe.  The beauty and simplicity of this is that I only need the one macro to set *all* of the GPIO properties!

BTW, feel free to reuse if you feel it worthy.  Just remember to give me a little shout out!

## Couple of notes

- This does not work for `void*`, `intXX_t **` (or any pointer referencing more than one pointer and therefore `&(int[n])` even though `(void *)ARR == (void *)&ARR`).
- `__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(char), int8_t, ...)` evaluates to false.
- `(uintptr_t)((X)+1) - (uintptr_t)(X) != 1` is a test for pointer math.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? (StackOverflow is for practical problems, not brainteasers)

Comment: You might want to look at C11 type-generic expressions, but it can't handle arrays of unspecified length.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did look at using `_Generic` first but (perhaps ironically) it was not generic enough.

Comment: @nneonneo lolz, I suspected the first comment would be "why?"  Wouldn't it be 'practical' to have better type casting in C? :-p

Comment: @Nate: I'm probably just not seeing the applications here since I've never wanted such a macro. Under what circumstances would this be useful? Maybe you can add those to the question.

Comment: In one place you have `ORDINARY_TYPE` that you don't define, and in another place you have `BASE_TYPE` you don't use. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @nneonneo I have added a use case but I fear it will just drudge up more questions if you are not familiar with the subject.

Comment: @ams Yes, that was a mistake.  Fixed, thank you!

Comment: Looks to me like this code is trying to be too clever. It would be better practice to *require* that `_prop` is always a pointer, or non-pointer type, and make it an error not to be. The indecisive spec is making the code non-portable and hard to maintain.

Comment: @ams Hence why I posted the question here.  Requiring `_prop` to be a pointer or non-pointer does not even remotely solve the problem - as far as I can tell anyways.  Perhaps you would entertain the possibility and write up a solution below for me?  (please?)

Comment: The crux of the problem is that you can't find the size of a type from its pointer if you can't dereference it, but it's an error to dereference a non-pointer, even in an else-clause. If you could *know* that the dereference is safe, or else know that you don't ever need to, then you have more freedom to write your type-independent macros.